# How to fix the open_basedir restriction error?

Tags: php, debugging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s):](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846882/open-basedir-restriction-in-effect-file-is-not-within-the-allowed-paths)

Hy  I have a script called dataface, on a shared host it outputs  all the time this warning

```
    Warning: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir restriction in effect. 
File(/usr/local/lib/php/Dataface/FormTool/text.php) is not within the allowed path(s):
 (/home/:/usr/lib/php:/tmp) in /home/a4385243/public_html/dataface/Dataface/FormTool.php on line 654
```

How can i fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

`open_basedir` is a setting limiting access to certain directories for PHP scripts.

You are not including the line from your script that throws the error, but if I'd had to guess, I'd say your script is including `Dataface/FormTool/text.php` somehow wrongly (maybe it would have to be `../Dataface....` or something).

PHP then starts searching for the file in the `include_path` and gets stopped by the `open_basedir` restriction.