# "open_basedir restriction in effect" php error on VPS

Tags: php, zend-framework, plesk

I'm trying to deploy a Zend Framework Application on my VPS.

My plan was to upload the entire application to the `/var/www/vhosts/my.domain/httpdocs` folder , and then change the `document root` setting in my Plesk Panel to httpdocs/public.

However, when I do this I get the above error.

There are answers on here, but none that exactly match my situation. I'm hoping for someone who has specific advice for my situation. (changing document root in Plesk Panel)

Comment: possible duplicate of [open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s):](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846882/open-basedir-restriction-in-effect-file-is-not-within-the-allowed-paths)

Comment: when you are getting this error?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Of course, the PHP `open_basedir` setting must be updated to include the new document root.

Yet I do not know how to do this in Plesk.