# Cakephp Warning: is_dir() [function.is-dir]: open_basedir restriction in effect

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cpanel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s):](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846882/open-basedir-restriction-in-effect-file-is-not-within-the-allowed-paths)

I uploaded my cakephp site to my web hosting server using cPanel...

And I got a list of errors after I uploaded the site.

```
Warning: is_dir() [function.is-dir]: open_basedir restriction in effect.
File(/usr/php4/lib/php/cake/libs) is not within the allowed path(s):
(/home/sumykids:/usr/lib/php:/usr/php4/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/usr/local/php4/lib/php:/tmp) in ...
```

Anyone knows how to solve it?

I try adding .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>    RewriteEngine on    RewriteRule    ^$
app/webroot/    [L]    RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]   
php_value     include_path .
</IfModule>
```

It doesn't work too...

Comment: this one may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846882/open-basedir-restriction-in-effect-file-is-not-within-the-allowed-paths

Comment: do I see "/php4/" in that file path???? Please tell me you're not actually still using PHP4?

Answer (score 0):

> modify the open_basedir settings on your httpd configuration file.

From here: [stackoverflow.com/questions/1846882/...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846882/open-basedir-restriction-in-effect-file-is-not-within-the-allowed-paths)

Depending on your hosting, you may not have permissions to do so and you will have to ask them to do it for you.

If you are going to use CakePHP 2, you may have to upgrade to PHP5.

> [PHP 5.2.8 or greater](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation.html)