# open_basedir() warning with Symfony1.4

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, open-basedir

Often browsing my site I can see this php warning:

> `Warning: is_readable(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/var/www/vhosts/<my site>/httpdocs/apps/frontend/modules/.sf/config/config_handlers.yml) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/vhosts/<my site>/httpdocs/:/tmp/) in /var/www/vhosts/<my site>/httpdocs/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/config/sfConfigCache.class.php on line 305`

The real problem is that Google is indexing my pages with that warning...

As specify in the title, I'm using Symfony 1.4.18.
How can I solve it?

Is it a Symfony bug, or is a PHP kind of restriction that I can go around It?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The real problem is that Google is indexing my pages with that warning...

On your production server you should always have `display_errors = Off`.

1. Open your php.ini file.
2. Add display_errors = Off
3. restart Apache

opendir: Limit the files that can be opened by PHP to the specified directory-tree, including the file itself.

Check this answer : 
[open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s):](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846882/open-basedir-restriction-in-effect-file-is-not-within-the-allowed-paths)

Comment: Thank you very much...Thanks to your advice I foud that, among my site folders I had an .htaccess file (that I haven't seen before) with a string which displayed the errors. I hope I've found, and solved, my error...

Answer (score 0):

It is a webserver problem, because you're trying to access data on a different vhost. You need to add the location to open_basedir. You should find a configuration file under /var/www/vhosts//config/vhosts.conf. You can either add the new location you want to access or disable the open_basedir restriction.
To add a new location just edit the open_basedir part (exmample):

```
php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs:/tmp:/new/path/comes/here"
```

But in productive usage you should disable printing out errors. They should go to e.g. log files.