# Include a php file on a server with open_basedir restriction in effect

Tags: php, include, document-root

i am building a website on 000webhost.com
trying to include a php file using

```
<?php include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/main/meta.php") ?>
```

but the server says
    `Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '/main/meta.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/USER_NAME/public_html/index.php on line 5

Warning: include() [function.include]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/local/apache/htdocs/main/head.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/:/usr/lib/php:/tmp) in /home/USER_NAME/public_html/index.php on line 7`

What should I do any other way to include file (and i am not going for ../../main/meta.php) because my site have so many folders and subfolders and i dont wanna edit every file.

Is there any way to include files.
I have full .htaccess support.

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846882/open-basedir-restriction-in-effect-file-is-not-within-the-allowed-paths

Comment: are you sure $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] is set?

Comment: @GBD i tried that already and if I edit .htaccess according to first answer then i got 404 not found error.

Comment: @SanderRoesink What do you mean???? how can I set $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']??

Comment: @SanderRoesink thanks buddy for hint, the problem is solved :)