# open_basedir restriction in effect .htaccess

Tags: php

I am getting the error

```
Warning: fopen() [function.fopen]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s): (VIRTUAL_DOCUMENT_ROOT:/tmp/) in /www/elitno.net/s/p/anger2/home/site/classWebPage.php on line 83
```

My phpinfo file is here -> http://spaceranger2.elitno.net/phpinfo.php

The line where the error is occuring is here:

```
function openLink(){
    $this->fp = fopen($this->URL, "rb");
    array_shift($http_response_header);
    $this->headers = $http_response_header;
}
```

I only have access to .htaccess but not my php.ini file; i tried using this

```
open_basedir = "VIRTUAL_DOCUMENT_ROOT:/tmp/:/www/elitno.net/s/p/ranger2/home/site/"
```

but this generates `500 internal error`'s, any suggestions?

Comment: Can you share the value of `$this->URL` when the error is occuring? The most helpful value would be the output of `var_dump($this->URL)`.
You should also check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/2916429/964616 .

Comment: the result is string(1) "/"

Comment: Did the solution work out for you? If yes, consider marking it an answer and upvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally `fopen` is only allowed to open files to which the user running the script has access.

You have designed your function `openLink()` to actually open a particular URL. You should note that when using `fopen` it actually indicates opening a file on the disk. If you pass values like `/` or `/filename.txt` it is actually going to try and open the file on the disk at that **absolute** filesystem path.

From your question data you are telling `fopen` to open `/`. That's the root of the filesystem of the server. Your user definitely won't have access to it (and hence the error you see).

If you want to open a relative path to your website consider prefixing the site URL to the `$this->URL` variable before passing it to `fopen` to indicate that you are trying to open a URL.

You can do something on the following lines:

```
function openLink(){
    $siteURL = "http://www.example.com";
    $urlToOpen = $siteURL . $this->URL;
    $this->fp = fopen($urlToOpen, "rb");
    array_shift($http_response_header);
    $this->headers = $http_response_header;
}
```