# WordPress warnings when auto creating new folder for uploads

Tags: wordpress, permissions

Today I get this warnings in wordpress:

```
Warning: file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/testams/:/tmp:/usr/share/pear54) in /home/testams/domains/testams.serveriai.lt/public_html/SA/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1335

Warning: is_dir(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/testams/:/tmp:/usr/share/pear54) in /home/testams/domains/testams.serveriai.lt/public_html/SA/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1344

Warning: file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/testams/:/tmp:/usr/share/pear54) in /home/testams/domains/testams.serveriai.lt/public_html/SA/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1335

Warning: is_dir(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/testams/:/tmp:/usr/share/pear54) in /home/testams/domains/testams.serveriai.lt/public_html/SA/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1344

Warning: file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/testams/:/tmp:/usr/share/pear54) in /home/testams/domains/testams.serveriai.lt/public_html/SA/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1335

Warning: is_dir(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/testams/:/tmp:/usr/share/pear54) in /home/testams/domains/testams.serveriai.lt/public_html/SA/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1344

Warning: file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/testams/:/tmp:/usr/share/pear54) in /home/testams/domains/testams.serveriai.lt/public_html/SA/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1335

Warning: is_dir(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/testams/:/tmp:/usr/share/pear54) in /home/testams/domains/testams.serveriai.lt/public_html/SA/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1344
```

When I change Settings > Media > Organize my uploads into month- and year-based folders this warnings disapear, what can be wrong with permision creating folders, and how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Dupe: [open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s):](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846882/open-basedir-restriction-in-effect-file-is-not-within-the-allowed-paths)

The `open_basedir restriction in effect` is a common error on some shared hosts that have that directive in place for security. Ask your host to change that, or if you have access to .htaccess, try the change yourself; but the server may be configured to not allow you to override in .htaccess.