# When I try to openmy webpage I'm getting 'open_basedir restriction in effect'

Tags: php, apache

I'm getting this error from host server:

```
Warning: Unknown: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/www/zxq.net/k/u/p/kuptoje/htdocs/index.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (VIRTUAL_DOCUMENT_ROOT) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '/www/zxq.net/k/u/p/kuptoje/htdocs/index.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php') in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: It's a webserver misconfiguration or your `index.php` is placed in wrong directory.

Comment: I fail to see what your question is. This is not a debugging site; ask a more general question and provide more information. Right now all we know is that there is this error coming up. What operation were you trying to perform?

Comment: Do you have access to the server via ssh? Do you have root privileges? Is it your server or you use hosting?

Comment: @Garan, it is irrelevant what operation he is trying to do on webpage - his php script is outside VIRTUAL_DOCUMENT_ROOT.

Answer (score 1):

Some hosts set an open_basedir restriction. This means that only files from inside the set include_path are allowed.

your include_path is set to `'/usr/lib/php'` but you are trying to require a file from `'/www/zxq...'` and that is not in the allowed include_path.

Solutions are to set open_basedir off or to add your '/www' folder to the open_basedir include_path.
this should be done in your php.ini file (often located at /etc/php.ini) There you simply add the /www directory to you php.ini file. e.g. `include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/www/zxq.net'`

If you don't have access to your php.ini file you can try setting it in php: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php if that doesn't work they don't allow you to edit the include_path. Contact your host and let them fix the problem.

EDIT: as linked to in the comments. See this thread for more info: [open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s):](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846882/open-basedir-restriction-in-effect-file-is-not-within-the-allowed-paths)

Comment: Did you reed the entire answer? I quote 'If you don't have access to your php.ini...'

Comment: +1 for considering almost all possible options