# Wordpress creates bad path and is blocked by open_basedir

Tags: php, windows, wordpress, plesk, open-basedir

I'm trying to migrate some of my clients' sites to my new server and I get the following error on 2 sites that have the same setup.

> PHP Warning:  is_readable(): open_basedir restriction in effect.
>   File(C:\Inetpub\vhosts\somedomain.com\httpdocs/http://www.somedomain.com/wp-content/plugins/knxdt-bookmarks-wordpress-plugin/lang/knxdt_bookmarks-en_US.mo)
>   is not within the allowed path(s):
>   (;C:/Inetpub/vhosts/somedomain.com\;C:\Windows\Temp\;C:\Inetpub\vhosts\somedomain.com\httpdocs\;)
>   in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\somedomain.com\httpdocs\wp-includes\l10n.php on
>   line 339

As can be seen in the path passed by what I assume to be Wordpress, there's something wrong there (... \httpdocs/http://www.somedomain ...). Why is the path combined like that ? Is this a php, plesk or wordpress problem ?

I've put open_basedir to none using Plesk admin and both sites work like a charm.

My setup
Old server:
 Windows 2008
 Plesk 9
 PHP Version 5.2.13

New server
 Windows 2012
 Plesk 11 (latest at time of writing)
 PHP Version 5.4

Thanks

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1846882/1735890

Comment: Not really as his is a linux question and mine is Windows.  His is only about open_basedir and mine is more a question about the path that is used by open_basedir (...\httpdocs/http://...).  Where it comes from and especially why is there a physical path combined with a web address

Answer (score 0):

It's a maybe a bug in plugin, here the example of [bug in NextGen Gallery](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/nextgen-20-update-kills-website?replies=8#post-4807186)

I've make an universal dirty fix in file l10n.php on line 565 in function load_plugin_textdomain:

```
    .... 
if ( false !== $plugin_rel_path ) {
    $plugin_rel_path = preg_replace('/(^.+plugins)/', '', $plugin_rel_path); # this line added
    $path = WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/' . trim( $plugin_rel_path, '/' );
} else if
    ...
```