# Prevent "scandir(): open_basedir restriction in effect"

Tags: php, runtime-error

I have this code (it's part of the [leash shell](https://github.com/jcubic/leash) that list all exec files from $PATH)

```
private function executables($paths = array()) {
    $execs = array();
    foreach ($paths as $path) {
        foreach (scandir($path) as $item) {
            $full_path = $path . "/" . $item;
            if (!is_dir($full_path) && is_executable($full_path)) {
                $execs[] = $item;
            }
        }
    }
    return $execs;
}
```

it use exec function with `'echo -n $PATH'`

```
    $path = $this->shell($token, 'echo -n $PATH', '/');
    $settings['path'] = $path['output'];
    $paths = explode(":", $settings['path']);
    $settings['executables'] = $this->executables($paths);
```

but php display error `"scandir(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/local/bin) is not within the allowed path(s)"`, how to prevent it, I've try to wrap the code with try .. finaly with no success.

Comment: possible duplicate of [open\_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s):](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846882/open-basedir-restriction-in-effect-file-is-not-within-the-allowed-paths)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, simple don't use php at all (use shell to list executables):

```
    $cmd = 'IFS=:; find $PATH -maxdepth 1 -executable -type f -printf ' .
        "'%f\n' 2>/dev/null";
    $execs = $this->shell($token, $cmd, '/');
    $settings['executables'] = explode("\n", trim($execs['output']));
```

Comment: I ask this on Unix site http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120786/list-all-binaries-from-path it have better solution for list all executables.

Answer (score 0):

[`open_basedir`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) is a PHP config value that, if set, restricts what directories a given PHP application has access to; in your case, `/usr/local/bin` is not included in that list.

The simplest way around this is to modify the setting in your php.ini file (or your project / site's vhost file) to include `/usr/local/bin`; however, that could also be construed as a security issue (which `open_basedir` is meant to help protect against).

Are you sure you need your script to access this directory? If so, you should be safe to edit =]. If not, I'd recommend updating your script to only stay within the allowed directories.

Comment: I can't modify php.ini I need solution for php code. Maybe test if the path is not in restricted dir.

Comment: There is no way to go around this *within* PHP; you could use `ini_get()` to get the current `open_basedir` value(s) and check your paths against it to see if you're about to violate it or not. I'm not sure if a simple `try/catch` would help you here, but you might give that a try as well.

Answer (score 0):

A @ sign before scandir() should hide the error (i.e `@scandir($path)`), if that's what you mean. Of course, your code will not be able to get the listing, but you can handle the error without showing the ugly message to the user.