# PHP fatal errors with Wordpress 3.9.1 + store bought theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, windows-server, error-log

I've got a bunch of errors in my error.log that have caused my site to go down. A server reboot seemed to solve it. But I'd like to get some clarity on these as they may shut down the site again. All of this is running on a Windows server with IIS, PHP and MySQL.

One error is calls to an undefined function. The path is right. The file is there. The function is built into wordpress. But sometimes this fatal error is coming up:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function trailingslashit() in path\to\file\wp-settings.php on line 321
```

Does anyone know why it would fail intermittently? Or if there is a best practice solution to prevent this in the future.

I'm using it in this fashion:

```
define('BLOX_PATH', trailingslashit(get_template_directory_uri()).'framework/Pagebuilder/');
define('BLOX_DIR', trailingslashit(get_template_directory()).'framework/Pagebuilder/');
```

Also I'm seeing an abundance of these. It's related to a Wordpress plugin requested by the client. It's a warning about folder permission issues, that much I know. My question is, is it site crashing issue or is it more innocuous in nature?

```
PHP Warning:  is_readable(): open_basedir restriction in effect.
```

Any thoughts or suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The `trailingslashit` function is defined in `wp-includes/formatting.php`. So if you're using it prior to the line that reads `require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/formatting.php' );` in `wp-settings.php` the function won't exist yet, and you will get the error.

See [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846882/open-basedir-restriction-in-effect-file-is-not-within-the-allowed-paths) about the open_basedir restriction.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error when I moved website on wordpress to another server on Debian.

For me worked:

```
sudo apt install php7.4-mysql
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thanks. I adapted to my php's version and it worked.

but the question remains: why?
If I use XAMPP, this is not necessary, but if I use Caddy, it is.