# File is not within the allowed path

Tags: php, wordpress, timthumb

> `[Tue Jul 08 07:13:37 2014] [warn] [client 66.249.80.15] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/gt3-wp-cleanspace/timthumb/timthumb.php/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/post-cyberlaw.jpg) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/:/tmp/) in /datas/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/gt3-wp-cleanspace/timthumb/timthumb.php on line 896, referer: https://www.mydomain.com/1`

I get this Warning in Wordpress, after updating timthumb.php, I really don't have an idea on how to fix this, maybe there is need to change some server settings, but which one?, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

See this question for possible help:

[open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s):](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846882/open-basedir-restriction-in-effect-file-is-not-within-the-allowed-paths)

If you're in a shared hosting environment or are otherwise unable to modify configuration files, you'll need to contact your hosting provider.