# Installing Symfony2 on Synology NAS 5.1 home server

Tags: php, symfony, synology

I am new to Symfony framework and a little bit noobish on unix systems. I've manage to go through first two steps of install process (`//server_name/symfony/web/app_dev.php`) and got stuck on last one. I'm getting such error:

> ContextErrorException: Warning: is_dir(): open_basedir restriction in
>   effect. File(**/var/services/homes**) is not within the allowed path(s):
>   (/etc.defaults:/etc:/usr/syno/synoman:/tmp:/var/services/tmp:/var/services/web:/var/services/homes:/root:/usr/bin:**/var/services/homes:/volume1/homes**)
>   in
>   /volume1/web/symfonytest/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Process/ExecutableFinder.php
>   line 59

I've added this path to `open_basedir` (as bolded) but it still throwing this error. On synology /var/services/homes is a linked directory an points to /volume1/homes folder.

Can you girls/guys help me out if anyone of you have come across such issue or just know how to pass this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [open\_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s):](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846882/open-basedir-restriction-in-effect-file-is-not-within-the-allowed-paths)

Comment: Did it work? I used to have the same problem, but the simple change of the basedir in UI settings helped. But few days ago, I encountered an error while trying to change open_basedir saying "operation invalid." I also used to have /usr/bin/php:/volume1/@tmp/php in the open_basedir too, but I assume, that the newer version changed that. If the problem persists, try to ask official "in-system" help since PHP is implemented by Synology itself.

Comment: Hi. No, still strugling to make it work. I'll ask Synology specialists how can this be achieved. I'll let you know if there is some progress with this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same error append for me while I set open_basedire. I think the problem could come from the wrong symbolique link of homes in /var/services/homes. If you look at "homes" file it point to "/volume1/@fake_home_link". Obviously, homes was not a directory. What I did is pointing /var/services/homes to /root. Maybe you could create a "homes" folder in volume1. I don't know if it is the best solution but then It didn't show up the warning message.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this solution because previous one didn't work for me.

Comment: By the way, In the NAS interface, I completely let "open_basedir" field empty blank (and still check) in order to get rid of any problem (It couldn't be really secure in some way...)