# What should my open_basedir path be set as?

Tags: php, open-basedir

I have a website, built using a multisite WordPress set-up.

I've come across the following advice online:

> It is better to enforce a base directory (eg: "/var/www/") to prevent
>   PHP from accessing other directories in the filesystem.

What should I set my path to?

1. home/mysite/
2. home/mysite/public_html
3. home/mysite/public_html/something-else

Edit: For more accurate context, I'm configuring open_basedir via WHM to manage more than one website on a VPS.

Comment: Your question differs as you elaborate.... do you want to know **why** or **what**?

Comment: what of those is the document_root?

Comment: @ɴᴀᴛʜ The "what" is being asked. The "why" was a typo on my part. Question edited. Thanks for spotting.

Comment: @UnskilledFreak Am I correct to understand "document_root" as "home/"?

Comment: @UnskilledFreak If document_root refers to where www.mysite.com leads to, "home/mysite/public_html" is the answer to your question.

Comment: yep thats what i mean, thanks. Is your wp installed in this dir? If so, wp automatically read the right dir in multisite mode from that, so your open_base_dir should be your document_root eg. /home/mysite/public_html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846882/open-basedir-restriction-in-effect-file-is-not-within-the-allowed-paths

Comment: @UnskilledFreak Seeing as how I'm configuring my PHP settings via WHM for a VPS, I've found `Home » Security Center » PHP open_basedir Tweak` which already has the document_root path identified. It allows the enabling and per-site exclusion of the open_basedir protection. Cheers.

Comment: @UnskilledFreak Please add your comment as an answer to allow me to gain closure on this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOCUMENT_ROOT should always be open_basedir.

Is your wp installed in this dir? If so, wp automatically read the right dir in multisite mode from that, so your open_base_dir should be your document_root

Comment: Seeing as how I'm configuring my PHP settings via WHM for a VPS, I've found `Home » Security Center » PHP open_basedir Tweak` which already has the document_root path identified. It allows the enabling and per-site exclusion of the open_basedir protection using. Cheers.