# Symfony2 open_basedir error on shared hosting

Tags: php, apache, symfony

Hello i am trying to install symfony2 on a shared hosting but i can't get it working. Seems i get an open_basedir error that i don't know how to resolve it. I'm using PhP 5.3 so that shouldn't be a problem. On local pc it's working with wamp, but i need it on shared.I mention that i asked the hosting provider and i can't put open_basedir on off. Here is the error:

```
ContextErrorException in ExecutableFinder.php line 59:
Warning: is_dir() [<a href='function.is-dir'>function.is-dir</a>]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/php4/lib/php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/websoft:/usr/lib/php:/usr/php4/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/usr/local/php4/lib/php:/tmp)
in ExecutableFinder.php line 59
at ErrorHandler->handleError('2', 'is_dir() [<a href='function.is-dir'>function.is-dir</a>]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/php4/lib/php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/websoft:/usr/lib/php:/usr/php4/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/usr/local/php4/lib/php:/tmp)', '/home/websoft/public_html/symfony24-test/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Process/ExecutableFinder.php', '59', array('name' => 'java', 'default' => '/usr/bin/java', 'extraDirs' => array(), 'searchPath' => array('/home/websoft', '/usr/lib/php', '/usr/php4/lib/php', '/usr/local/lib/php', '/usr/local/php4/lib/php', '/tmp'), 'dirs' => array('/home/websoft', '/usr/lib/php'), 'path' => '/usr/php4/lib/php'))
at is_dir('/usr/php4/lib/php') in ExecutableFinder.php line 59
at ExecutableFinder->find('java', '/usr/bin/java') in Configuration.php line 67
at Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\DependencyInjection\{closure}() in VariableNode.php line 54
at VariableNode->getDefaultValue() in ArrayNode.php line 241
at ArrayNode->finalizeValue(array('debug' => true, 'use_controller' => array('enabled' => true), 'bundles' => array(), 'filters' => array('cssrewrite' => array()))) in BaseNode.php line 303
at BaseNode->finalize(array('debug' => true, 'use_controller' => array('enabled' => true), 'bundles' => array(), 'filters' => array('cssrewrite' => array()))) in Processor.php line 37
at Processor->process(object(ArrayNode), array(array('debug' => true, 'use_controller' => false, 'bundles' => array(), 'filters' => array('cssrewrite' => null)), array('use_controller' => true))) in Processor.php line 50
at Processor->processConfiguration(object(Configuration), array(array('debug' => true, 'use_controller' => false, 'bundles' => array(), 'filters' => array('cssrewrite' => null)), array('use_controller' => true))) in AsseticExtension.php line 44
at AsseticExtension->load(array(array('debug' => true, 'use_controller' => false, 'bundles' => array(), 'filters' => array('cssrewrite' => null)), array('use_controller' => true)), object(ContainerBuilder)) in MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php line 50
at MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process(object(ContainerBuilder)) in MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php line 39
at MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process(object(ContainerBuilder)) in Compiler.php line 117
at Compiler->compile(object(ContainerBuilder)) in ContainerBuilder.php line 614
at ContainerBuilder->compile() in bootstrap.php.cache line 2564
at Kernel->initializeContainer() in bootstrap.php.cache line 2343
at Kernel->boot() in bootstrap.php.cache line 2374
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in app_dev.php line 22
```

Comment: The problems is with your apache settings. You are trying to set the base directory to a page that falls outside the allowed directories that apache is configured for. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846882/open-basedir-restriction-in-effect-file-is-not-within-the-allowed-paths

Comment: i don't have acces to any php config files, that means i can't fix this right?:)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and and removing Debug::enable(); from app_dev.php solved it.