# Making a directory based on username?

Tags: php

I am trying to create a directory with mkdir code.
When I use this code :

```
mkdir("test");
```

then, the "test" directory will be created.
But when I try something like this

```
mkdir($_SESSION['username']);
```

then, I got an error saying

> Warning: mkdir(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File() is not within the allowed path(s)

What does this mean?
I also tried

```
$path = $_SESSION['username'];
mkdir($path);
```

and

```
mkdir("".$_SESSION['username']."");
```

but it gives me the same error message.
What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Have you thought to reflect upon what the error actually means?

Comment: What is the output of: `var_dump($_SESSION['username']);` ?

Comment: Have you tried outputting the value of `$path` to check for slashes or dots?

Comment: @Rizier123 - String(8) username.. I'm logged in without problems...

Comment: @StevenTomko What is the **exact** output?

Comment: @Rizier123 - string(8) "Fregbind"

Comment: Are you saying that you login and it creates your directory without a problem, but if someone else tries, it throws an error? Have you checked to see what username they are trying to use - such as the username "/etc/sysconfig".

Comment: That's why they have manuals http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: @kainaw - no i'm not... It does not create even mine directory (Fregbind)...

Comment: @Fred-ii- - I did read this a while ago before I posted this

Comment: You're creating a folder, or trying to create one with no permissions set for it. Plus, did you start the session? Are you checking for errors?

Comment: @Fred -ii- - Lol you asked if I started session? Please, read all the comments. Var dump is my name... of course I did start session ffs
And I did error reporting but nothing came on

Comment: The `f`'s am sure those stand for "fabulous friend", right? ;-) knew it. Ok, well take it up with the answer given below; they seem to be sure of their shot. We've said enough in comments now.

Comment: uhm.. Okay, it's working and I have no idea why... I swear that i did not change anything since I posted. I only used var_dump and uhm... My question is .. why is it working now without that error?...-____- the code is same as it was before I posted this o_q

Comment: @StevenTomko [**We now what you mean!**](http://s2.quickmeme.com/img/ca/cab0642c5c16b270935e65076d152a8d2e1d12dcf2520ee629b47a03dc86677c.jpg)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1846882/ similar issue. Same link in the answer below, is contained in that Q&A. I'm going to go walk my dog now.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you prefix the folder name with the full path to where you want to create the folders. Ie, if you are trying to create folders under `/tmp/users` then you might use code like:

```
mkdir('/tmp/users/' . $_SESSION['username']);
```

You also need to make sure that you have configured PHP to allow you to access that path. See the open_basedir ini directive: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir

Comment: File permissions might be an issue as well, you have to make sure the directory is writable by the web server.

Comment: @JosephCrawford OP: *"And I did error reporting but nothing came on"* - Had it been a permissions issue, it would have told them so; least one would think it would. Who knows.