# Warnings after moving Wordpress installation

Tags: wordpress

Since I reinstalled a website on a different hosting and moved the database and everything, I keep getting a lot of error messages when trying to open the website (www.pandasnacozinha.com.br). Some of the errors are:

```
Warning: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/u332015957/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2015/05) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/pandasnacozinha.com.br) in /home/pandasnacozinha.com.br/www/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1496

Warning: is_dir() [function.is-dir]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/u332015957/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2015) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/pandasnacozinha.com.br) in /home/pandasnacozinha.com.br/www/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1501

Warning: is_dir() [function.is-dir]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/u332015957/public_html/wp-content/uploads) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/pandasnacozinha.com.br) in /home/pandasnacozinha.com.br/www/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1501
```

I noticed something: my root directory in the old hosting was "public_html". The new hosting calls the root directory "www". I believe this is what might be causing the problem, but I don't know how to solve it.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Thank you,
Giovanna

Comment: The problem has to do with open basedir restriction. You can Google the term if you want to learn more about it. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846882/open-basedir-restriction-in-effect-file-is-not-within-the-allowed-paths

Comment: Can you post the PHP code of the functions.php lines that the warnings mention?