# Warning open_basedir restriction in effect

Tags: effect, restriction, open-basedir

I know what exactly the problem is. I need to fix my open_basedir restriction. But the problem is, I don't know how exactly.

```
PHP Warning:  is_dir(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/local/php55/lib/php/) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/converter/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/usr/local/php55/lib/php/) in /home/converter/domains/converter.playslim.com/public_html/lib/Symfony/Component/Process/ExecutableFinder.php on line 59
PHP Warning:  is_dir(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/local/php55/lib/php/) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/converter/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/usr/local/php55/lib/php/) in /home/converter/domains/converter.playslim.com/public_html/lib/Symfony/Component/Process/ExecutableFinder.php on line 59
```

Comment: Hi, always remember to Google the error message first! `Warning open_basedir restriction in effect` yields plenty of results; the first hit is on this very site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [open\_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s):](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846882/open-basedir-restriction-in-effect-file-is-not-within-the-allowed-paths)

Comment: That didn't help solving my problem.

Answer (score -1):

Change the following code with this one

```
if (file_exists(DIR_SYSTEM . 'vendor/autoload.php')) { 
    require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'vendor/autoload.php'); 
}
```

In `system/startup.php`:

```
if (is_file(DIR_SYSTEM . '../../vendor/autoload.php')) {
    require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . '../../vendor/autoload.php');
}
```