# file_get_contents(): open_basedir restriction in effect

Tags: php

I got a strange error message:

> file_get_contents(): open_basedir restriction in effect.
>   File(/path/to/file) is not within the allowed path(s): 
>   (/Library/WebServer:/var/tmp:/path/to)

As seen, the path to the file has been added in the allowed paths, why does open_basedir restriction remain in effect?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [open\_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s):](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846882/open-basedir-restriction-in-effect-file-is-not-within-the-allowed-paths)

Comment: nope. my setting is correct..

Comment: You read fast...did you scroll until http://stackoverflow.com/a/11233478/797495 ?

Comment: yes. i saw this article earlier :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’d need to check permissions of /path and /path/to. Somehow it didn’t show `You don't have permission to access` but this `open_basedir restriction in effect` message.