# L5 artisan open_basedir restriction

Tags: php, apache, laravel, laravel-artisan, open-basedir

Just need some help on how to fix this `open_basedir` restriction
I've tried to run a command `php artisan`

This is the error msg:

```
is_file(): open_basedir restriction in effect.
File(/opt/php-7.0/bin/php) is not within the allowed path(s):
(/home/u823993344:/tmp:/var/tmp:/opt/php-7.0/pear:/usr/local/bin:/etc/pki/tls/certs)
```

I tried setting `php.ini`

```
open_basedir = "/home/u823993344"
```

but still doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Update:
i found what causes the error, its the in `vendor/symfony/process/PhpExecutableFinder.php` `is_file(PHP_BINARY)`

`PHP_BINARY` value is /opt/php-7.0/bin/php-cgi

Comment: Possible duplicate of [open\_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s):](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846882/open-basedir-restriction-in-effect-file-is-not-within-the-allowed-paths)

Comment: Which `php.ini` are you modifying?

Comment: @linuxartisan i added a php.ini in the root of the project

Comment: Well then try `$ php --ini` command and see whether that file is present in the output.

Comment: @linuxartisan its not present,
i manage to found the cause,
`PHP_BINARY` value is /opt/php-7.0/bin/php-cgi

and if you run `is_file(PHP_BINARY)` this cause open_basedir restriction