# how to generate download link Files that are located on another server in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I put my videos on my Shared web host and user can direct download all files. but I want to hide my actual file paths and make time-limited download links.
if files were on same server it is work fine.
when I use  this code :

```
return response()->download('/home2/alihoss1/domains/alihossein.ir/public_html/dl/video/MySql/Sql1.mp4');
```

i see this error :

```
is_file(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home2/alihoss1/domains/alihossein.ir/public_html/dl/video/MySql/Sql1.mp4) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home2/alihosse/domains/alihossein.ir/:/tmp/:/usr/local/php-7.0/lib/php/)
```

What solution would you recommend ؟
videos and laravel Project are not same host.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [open\_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s):](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846882/open-basedir-restriction-in-effect-file-is-not-within-the-allowed-paths)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.file-get-contents.php) to get the file from the other server. This would lead to unneccessary traffic though because server 1 would download the file from server 2. That applies also to scp etc.

You should think about encryption:

```
$hash = encrypt([
    'valid_to' => strtotime('+30 minutes'),
    'file_path' => '/home2/alihoss1/domains/alihossein.ir/public_html/dl/video/MySql/Sql1.mp4'
]);

return redirect('http://server2.example/download/hash/' . urlencode($hash));
```

You then need to decrypt this on the second server with the same key. If you do not have laravel installed there, you can implement your own decrypting functionality (see: [laravel openssl encryption](https://github.com/neoxia/laravel-openssl-encryption/blob/master/src/Neoxia/LaravelOpensslEncryption/Encrypter.php#L92)).