# PHP error on website - Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required

Tags: php

I have inherited a hosted website and I'm getting the below 3 errors:

> -Warning: Unknown: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/rehworkc/public_html/framework/main.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (0) in Unknown on line 0***
>
> -Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in Unknown on line 0***
>
> -Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '/home/rehworkc/public_html/framework/main.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/php') in Unknown on line 0***

I suspect it could be a permissions issue but not sure how to resolve. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [open\_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s):](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846882/open-basedir-restriction-in-effect-file-is-not-within-the-allowed-paths)

Comment: Why do you "suspect" a permission issue? It definitely _says_ so.

Answer (score 0):

Just for future reference in case it helps someone else, the issue was in an environment.php file, it had these two flags:

ini_set('safe_mode', 'Off');
ini_set('open_basedir', 'Off');

having open_basedir set to off meant it wasn't able to use any of the PHP files.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because SELinux is preventing read access to the file you are trying to access,

use `restore con/home/rehworkc/public_html/framework/main.php` to restore access to the file

Hope this helps.

Futher reading on this [link](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/apache-2-warning-unknown-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied-814037/)

Answer (score 0):

You might **not** be in the directory where you've installed laravel. Try **cd** into the correct directory.