# open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s):

Tags: php, codeigniter, adminlte

I'm getting this error on admin page upload on my site. I've never gotten it before and nothing was changed recently for me to begin getting this error...

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: disk_total_space(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/u577342213:/tmp:/var/tmp:/opt/php-5.6/pear:/usr/local/bin:/etc/pki/tls/certs)

Filename: admin/Dashboard_model.php

Line Number: 22
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [open\_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s):](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846882/open-basedir-restriction-in-effect-file-is-not-within-the-allowed-paths)

Answer (score 0):

For resolve this error, you must edit the file httpd.conf of your new uploading server as follows .

Its found in -  **/etc/httpd/httpd.conf** 
Open the file httpd.conf, find the parameter open_basedir. And set it to none.
 
  **php_admin_value open_basedir none**

I hope it will solve your issue.