# Commands working fine in putty but not using exec() in PHP

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, terminal

So I have installed shhavel's facerec (https://github.com/shhavel/facerec) on my VPS (Ubuntu 14.04.5) and it works perfectly fine when I use it from within putty:

```
facerec list
jenniferlawrence
emmawatson
```

However, from within PHP when using the exec() function, the only command that works is facerec -help, all other commands produce an error similar to the following:

**facerec list 2>&1**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/facerec", line 359, in 
sys.exit(__main__())
File "/usr/local/bin/facerec", line 356, in __main__
return args.func(args)
File "/usr/local/bin/facerec", line 159, in list
for subject in os.listdir(subjects_directory):
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './subjects'
```

**The PHP script:**

```
exec('facerec list 2>&1', $output);
foreach($output as $string) {
    echo $string."<br>";
}
```

How do I approach fixing this problem?

Comment: Are you sure your php script has right permissions to run those commands using exec?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found the problem:**

The "subjects"-folder was located in /root/ which the PHP script did not have the permission to access

**Possible solutions:**

- change open_basedir in PHP settings to none (See here: [open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s):](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846882/open-basedir-restriction-in-effect-file-is-not-within-the-allowed-paths))
- install shhavel/facerec as the right user (not as root)
- move the subjects-folder to a different location and change the facerec python script accordingly