# Warning: unlink() but file is removed

Tags: php

I am using the code below remove an image file.
The files **is removed** but there is still an error shown. Any suggestions?

> Warning: unlink() [function.unlink]: open_basedir restriction in
>   effect. File() is not within the allowed path(s):

```
<?php
session_start(); //session start

if(isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    $check_image = glob('../uploads/logo_'.$_SESSION['relatie_id'].'.*');
    unlink($check_image[0]);

    echo '<div class="alert alert-success text-center" role="alert">Met succes verwijderd.</div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s):](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846882/open-basedir-restriction-in-effect-file-is-not-within-the-allowed-paths)

Comment: Look at open_basedir option in php.ini: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir

You can use "chdir()" to change to that directory, or change open_basedir on runtime

Answer (score 0):

Try this function

```
 function delete($dir, $file) {
   $file = $dir . '/' . $file;
   if ((file_exists($file)) && (@unlink($file)) ) {
     return true;
   }
   return false;
 }
```