# VestaCP: open_basedir restriction while using app/autoload.php

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.3, vesta

I deploy Symfony3 project on server (Ubuntu 16.04, PHP 7.0.18).
I use VestaCP, create symlinl `public_shtml -> www/web` and place project in `www` directory.

I execute following commands:

- git clone
- composer install
- setfacl (from official Symfony documentation)

In error log I see that messages:

> PHP Warning:  require(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/admin/web/project/www/app/autoload.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/admin/web/project/public_shtml:/home/admin/tmp) in /home/admin/web/project/www/web/app.php on line 6
>
> PHP Warning:  require(/home/admin/web/project/www/app/autoload.php): failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in /home/admin/web/project/www/web/app.php on line 6
>
> PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/admin/web/project/www/web/../app/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/admin/web/project/www/web/app.php on line 6

What do I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846882/open-basedir-restriction-in-effect-file-is-not-within-the-allowed-paths

Comment: Possible duplicate of [open\_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s):](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846882/open-basedir-restriction-in-effect-file-is-not-within-the-allowed-paths)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `open_basedir` parameter in config for apache (`/home/admin/conf/web/apache2.conf` and `/home/admin/conf/web/sapache2.conf`) to point to your newly created folder `/home/admin/web/project/www`:

```
<Directory /home/admin/web/project/www/web>
    AllowOverride All
    Options +Includes -Indexes +ExecCGI
    php_admin_value open_basedir /home/admin/web/project/www:/home/admin/tmp
    php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /home/admin/tmp
    php_admin_value session.save_path /home/admin/tmp
</Directory>
```

VestaCP uses `open_basedir` restriction to make more secure default configuration.

Also if you plan to add more websites to your server I recommend you to make special apache config template for your symfony projects at path `/usr/local/vesta/data/templates/web/apache2/`. You can copy default templates `default.tpl` and `default.stpl` as new files `symfony.tpl` and `symfony.stpl` where you can change `open_basedir`, `DocumentRoot` and `Directory` parameters. If you will not do it: every time after adding/updating configurations for your user's sites VestaCP will replace your current configuration with new generated config using default template and you will need to edit it again.