# Yii2 Glide Sign image Error: tempnam(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp) is not within the allowed path(s):

Tags: yii2

I try glide sign image with Yii 2 Glide extendsion

That my url: [Url demo](http://cenleasing.vn/storage/cache/1/cD5toKbFU8SV-P0SGLQVWSnGVkP-y7fI.jpg/75?w=360&h=243&fit=crop&s=2ffaa5f5d70101eab69ed182fe888d9a)

So has error:

```
tempnam(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/admin/web/cenleasing.vn/public_html:/home/admin/tmp)
```

So how can i fix it

Comment: i see sample problem here, so i can't know exact solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846882/open-basedir-restriction-in-effect-file-is-not-within-the-allowed-paths

Comment: I folow guider so it work https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/open_basedir-and-safe_mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution with vestacp.

The file to edit was:

```
/home/admin/conf/web/httpd.conf
```

And I had to comment:

```
php_admin_value open_basedir /home/admin/web/xxx.com/public_html:/home/admin/tmp
```