# PHP 7.0 move_uploaded_file() doesn't work

Tags: php, html, vue.js

I'm working on my own VPS server. My codes are down there. I changed the folder permissions to 777. I am using PHP 7.0 and apache2. I tried turning it off in Safe mode. I don't see files in the Temp folder. It also does not move to the folder I specified. Where am I doing wrong?

-Unknown: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/) in Unknown on line 0, referer: http://localhost:8080/

-File upload error - unable to create a temporary file in Unknown on line 0, referer: http://localhost:8080/

i am new user on apache2

```
//$_FILES["UploadImage]["name"] = eg. image.png

$path = '/var/www/uploads/';

$yuklenecek_dosya = $path . basename($_FILES['UploadImage']['name']);
var_dump(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['UploadImage']['tmp_name'], $yuklenecek_dosya));
// result : bool->false
```

Comment: Anything in your error log? It sounds like if `move_uploaded_file` can't move a file, it'll throw a warning and return false.

Comment: I can use for this var_dump(). It's give me bool - false 
Also i tried $_FILES["UploadImage"]["error"] this is give me 0 (no error file moved)

Comment: @MahirAltınkaya check your server's PHP error log.

Comment: When you run "ls /var/www/uploads", what do you see?

Comment: Hi. added main post 2 error codes.

Comment: i run in putty  ls /var/www/uploads. its gived me total 0.  but i dont know what is that

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846882/open-basedir-restriction-in-effect-file-is-not-within-the-allowed-paths

Comment: Hello Nick. my open_basedir = /var/www/

Comment: Open your `php.ini` and edit open_base_dir entry to include tmp?

Comment: i tried it. tmp files in /var. i use new open_basedir =/var but still i cant upload image .

Comment: You need quotes around the string: `open_base_dir = "/tmp/"`, you also need to reload the conf file.

Comment: i will try fastly

Comment: Hello Kisaragi. i tried open_basedir = /tmp/. after my page gave me 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to produce the solution simply. I saw that the permits I gave were not working. I did the following respectively.

```
php.ini -> open_basedir = none
php.ini -> system_temp_dir = "/ var / www / tmp /"
chmod 0777 / var / www / tmp /
chmod 0777 / var / www / uploads
and change php script

$ path = '/ var / www / uploads /';
```

this is work know. Thank you everyone.