# Laravel and WordPress Integration

Tags: wordpress, laravel

I have created a service provider in order to include wordpress.

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

class WordpressCustomServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $bootstrapFilePath = '../../blog/wp-load.php';

    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        // wp_enqueue_style('app', '/app/public/app.css');
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //echo dirname(__FILE__); die;
        //
        // Load wordpress bootstrap file
         if(File::exists($this->bootstrapFilePath)) {
            require_once $this->bootstrapFilePath;
        } else throw new \RuntimeException('WordPress Bootstrap file not found!');
    }
}
```

I have also included in class in provider list in app.php
When i run the code. It gives me the  error:

> "file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect.
>   File(../../blog/wp-load.php) is not within the allowed path(s):
>   (/var/www/vhosts/ser.com/:/tmp/)"

My Blog Structure is like:

```
app/  ---->Laravel
blog/ ---->wordpress
```

Yes I know the problem comes when we include path outside webroot. But blog folder is inside.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [open\_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s):](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846882/open-basedir-restriction-in-effect-file-is-not-within-the-allowed-paths)

Answer (score -1):

I just modified the path

```
protected $bootstrapFilePath = 'blog/wp-load.php';
```

and it works.