# PHP Cannot Move Uploaded File

Tags: php, html, forms, upload

I use this `form` to upload an image to my `PHP`:

```
<form method="post" action="http://my.domain/media.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10485760" />
    <input type="file" name="mediafile"></input>
    <input type="submit"></input>
</form>
```

And I use this `PHP` code to retrieve the uploaded file (image):

```
$mfn = "./upload_test.png";
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['mediafile']['tmp_name'], $mfn)) {
    if (file_exists($mfn)) {
        echo 'success';
    } else {
        echo 'Uploaded file didn\'t move to the requested path.';
        print_r($_FILES);
    }
} else {
    echo 'move_uploaded_file error<br/>';
    print_r(error_get_last());
    echo '<br/>';
    print_r($_FILES);
}
```

When I click the submit button, the `move_uploaded_file` returns an error. So, I caught debug data with `print_r(error_get_last())`:

```
Array (
[type] => 2
[message] => move_uploaded_file(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File() is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/username/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/)
[file] => /home/username/domains/my.domain/public_html/media.php
[line] => 96 )
```

and with `print_r($_FILES)`:

```
Array (
[mediafile] => Array (
    [name] => test.png
    [type] => image/png
    [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpvoQr3i
    [error] => 0
    [size] => 38207 )
)
```

**NOTE: I can't edit php.ini or any admin settings.**

Comment: The error message seems to be pretty clear. The PHP script is not allowed to write into that directory. You need to write to one of the 4 directories listed in the `open_basedir` list. Or change your `php.ini` setting to add more directories.

Comment: Hmm... did you delete my comment? Or is S/O messing up... I flagged this as a dupe to that one, yet it claims you did?! How strange.

Comment: @Barmar, what should I do? How can I move the uploaded file?

Comment: @Dammeul When a question is closed as a duplicate, comments that mention the same question are automatically deleted because they're redundant. The close notice only shows users who voted to close, not those who flagged (you don't have enough rep to cast close votes).

Comment: @Barmar, please read the end of edited question.

Comment: Ahh now I know! Thought I was losing my mind!!!  One day I will, maybe ;)

Comment: Where does the filename `media.png` come from? The filename in the code is `upload_test.png`.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're getting the error, since `/home/username/` is in the list, and the filename is `/home/username/domains/my.domain/public_html/media.php`

Comment: `upload_test.png` is the path to save the file to server.

Comment: The error says `File()`, so, there is no path between parentheses. But it should be as the same of `tmp_name`, but it isn't. When I installed WordPress, I could upload media, such as images. But I don't know how do this work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [open\_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s):](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846882/open-basedir-restriction-in-effect-file-is-not-within-the-allowed-paths)

Comment: Have you check folder permissions ?

Comment: Yes. I'd check that.