# Moving NginX /var/www/MyWeb to a USB drive. Linux Buster

Tags: php, linux, nginx, debian-buster

I'm new to NginX and PHP.  I have just completed a basic NginX installation with PHP.  When I use a browser to access the server address, 192.168.10.11, I get the correct output from the sample index.php file in the .../public-html folder.

However, I want my web to be on an external drive, so I used this:

```
sudo rsync -av /var/www/ /mnt/usbdrive/website
```

Since this was to a fat32 USB memory stick, the rsync threw errors as it could not transfer the file permissions, but the files and content were copied over.

I edited the /sites-available/default file and change the root statement to

```
root /mnt/usbdrive/website/default/public-html;
```

Now, when I use the browser to go to that server address, I get this output

```
no input file specified
```

If I code a simple index.html file with "hello world", that works.  But the index.php file still does not.

What am I missing?

Comment: This installation is on a Raspberry Pi v3B.  The OS in Buster.  It was never on a PC...Yes, I restarted the server after the rsync and any changes to the configuration or index files.

Comment: I found the answer from this reference: ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846882/open-basedir-restriction-in-effect-file-is-not-within-the-allowed-paths

Answer (score 0):

you must restart the web server.
did it work for you when it was on the pc?

Comment: This should be comment not an answer